# Limit of sequence to prove $f$ differentiable at point $c$

Tags: real-analysis

Given that $f\colon\mathbb R \to \mathbb R, c \in \mathbb R$ and $f$ is differentiable on $\mathbb R$, show that:

(1) $\displaystyle f'(c) = \lim_{n\to\infty} \ n(f(c+\frac{1}{n}) - f(c))$

(2) Show by example the existence of sequence $x_n = c$ doesn't imply $f'(c)$ exists

Proving (1) is fairly simple,

$$x_n = c+ n^{-1} \hspace{0.2cm}\text{   with   }\hspace{0.2cm} \lim_{x_n \to c} = c$$

and thus using the def'n of derivative at $x=c$:

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{f(c+n^{-1}) - f(c)}{c+n^{-1} - c} \implies \lim_{n\to \infty} \ n(f(c+\frac{1}{n}) - f(c))$$

(2) I'm not sure how to show that the existence of the sequence $x_n$ that goes to c doesn't necessarily imply the existence of $f'(c)$?

Comment: What does $n$ approach ?

Comment: infinite is what n approaches

Comment: Existence  of limit $f(x_n)$ for one sequence $(x_n)$ doesn't give limit in general.

Comment: right I just can't think of an example for $x_n$ that shows this, which sequence converges to c

Comment: The first part of the question says $f$ is differentiable so $f'(c)$ exists by that for real $c$ already.

Comment: The way part (2) is stated seems a bit unclear. If you are looking for an example of "$\lim_{n \to \infty} n \left[f\left(c+\frac{1}{n}\right)-f(c) \right]=L$ BUT $f$ is not differentiable at $c$" then just consider $c=0$ and $f(x)=|x|$.